# How to display values only into csv file and also how to add field name for that...!

Tags: php, arrays

When I call download case it automatically exported to CSV format but the output display like this:

---

```
    Array
    (
        [post_subject] => test
        [post_feel] => 
        [post_cselect] => option01
        [post_daselect] => option03
        [post_dmpc] => dgfdg
        [post_cmg] => trgbrt
        [post_pkmg] => dfvdsf
        [post_wfid] => gfddftg
        [post_cpn] => fdgfdgd
        [post_datee] => test
        [post_pjn] => fdgfsddh
        [post_fpn] => dgfhsdfd
        [post_erselect] => option09
        [post_wgw] => rettr
        [post_aprfselect] => option11
        [post_bb] => wcdfrsrd
        [post_dtselect] => option13
        [post_cgdselect] => option15
        [post_txtselect] => option18
        [post_barselect] => option19
        [post_fselect] => option21
        [post_iselect] => option23
        [post_sselect] => option25
        [post_trselect] => option27
        [post_dmselect] => option29
    )
```

This my code:

```
 case 'downloadd':
 $sql = 'SELECT forum_id
         FROM ' . POSTS_TABLE . '
         WHERE post_id = ' . $post_id;
 $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
 $f_id = (int) $db->sql_fetchfield('forum_id');
 $db->sql_freeresult($result);

 $forum_id = (!$f_id) ? $forum_id : $f_id;

 $sql = 'SELECT f.*, t.*, p.*, u.username, u.username_clean, u.user_sig, u.user_sig_bbcode_uid, u.user_sig_bbcode_bitfield
         FROM ' . POSTS_TABLE . ' p, ' . TOPICS_TABLE . ' t, ' . FORUMS_TABLE . ' f, ' . USERS_TABLE . " u
         WHERE p.post_id = $post_id
         AND t.topic_id = p.topic_id
         AND u.user_id = p.poster_id
         AND f.forum_id = t.forum_id ";
 if (!$sql) {
   $user->setup('posting');
   trigger_error('NO_POST_MODE');
 }

 $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
 $post_data = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
 $testt = array_slice($post_data,96,37);
 $filename = print_r($testt);

 header("Content-type: text/csv");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.csv");

 outputCSV($testt);
 $db->sql_freeresult($result);
 break;
```

**Please help me how to display values only into csv file and also how to add field name for that...!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the outputted data is not well formatted. It's not possible to export a PHP array as it is. It might be a comma (or some other special character) separated string.

Please modify your code this way. It will work for you

```
$output = '';
foreach (array_keys($testt) as $value) {
    $output .= $value.',';
}
$output = rtrim($output,",");
$output .= $value.'\n';

foreach ($testt as $key => $value) {
    $output .= $value.',';
}
$output = rtrim($output,",");


header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"');
echo($output);      
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you bro ...but i want to display array values only instead of index.so, how will i do that?

Comment: You please just remove the first loop from the code that I was given. It will work.